# Parallel QuickSort using TTask.Future<> appears to be hanging

Tags: delphi, parallel-processing, delphi-xe8

Just getting my feet wet with Delphi's new(ish) parallel library.

Below I have a simple VCL test form with a button where a random array of integer values is created and then sorted using a traditional, recursive QuickSort algorithm. This works fine, of course.

I've then tried to create and use a parallelized (sp?) version of the algorithm by making the recursive sub-partitioning calls from within a `TTask.Future<Boolean>`.

Unfortunately that does not have the expected outcome - instead, the code seems to keep spawning new threads and doesn't complete - at least not within a reasonable time (I let it run for several minutes where the non-parallel version completes in less than a second).

So what am I doing wrong here? (I'm using Delphi XE8, update1 here, in case that matters).

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm5 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form5: TForm5;

implementation
uses
  System.Threading;

{$R *.dfm}

type
  TIntArray = array[0..1000000-1] of Integer;
  PIntArray = ^TIntArray;

procedure InitializeArray(IA: PIntArray);
var
  i, j, tmp: Integer;
begin
  // init
  for i := 0 to 1000000-1 do
    IA[i] := i;
  // shuffle
  for i := 0 to 1000000-1 do begin
    j := random(1000000);
    tmp := IA[i];
    IA[i] := IA[j];
    IA[j] := tmp;
  end;
end;

{- traditional recursive QuickSort}
procedure Sort1R(IA: PIntArray; Left, Right: Integer);
var
  L, R, Pivot, Tmp: Integer;
begin
  Pivot := IA[(Left + Right) shr 1];
  L := Left;
  R := Right;
  repeat

    while IA[L] < Pivot do
      inc(L);

    while IA[R] > Pivot do
      dec(R);

    if L <= R then begin

      if L < R then begin

        Tmp := IA[L];
        IA[L] := IA[R];
        IA[R] := Tmp;

      end;

      inc(L);
      dec(R);

    end;

  until L > R;

  if Left < R then
    Sort1R(IA, Left, R);

  if Right > L then
    Sort1R(IA, L, Right);
end;

{- call traditional recursive QuickSort}
procedure Sort1(IA: PIntArray);
begin
  Sort1R(IA, 0, 999999);
end;

{- parallelized QuickSort using TTask.Future }
function Sort2R(IA: PIntArray; Left, Right: Integer): Boolean;
var
  L, R, Pivot, Tmp: Integer;
  FirstValue, SecondValue: IFuture <Boolean>;
begin
  Pivot := IA[(Left + Right) shr 1];
  L := Left;
  R := Right;
  repeat

    while IA[L] < Pivot do
      inc(L);

    while IA[R] > Pivot do
      dec(R);

    if L <= R then begin

      if L < R then begin

        Tmp := IA[L];
        IA[L] := IA[R];
        IA[R] := Tmp;

      end;

      inc(L);
      dec(R);

    end;

  until L > R;

  FirstValue := TTask.Future<Boolean>(
    function: Boolean
      begin
        if Left < R then
          Sort2R(IA, Left, R);
        Result := True;
      end);

  SecondValue := TTask.Future<Boolean>(
    function: Boolean
      begin
        if Right > L then
          Sort2R(IA, L, Right);
        Result := True;
      end);

  Result := FirstValue.Value and SecondValue.Value;

end;

{- call parallel recursive QuickSort}
procedure Sort2(IA: PIntArray);
begin
  Sort2R(IA, 0, 999999);
end;

{ - check that array got sorted}
procedure Check(IA: PIntArray);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for I := 1 to 999999 do
    if IA[I-1] > IA[I] then
      raise Exception.Create('Not sorted');
end;

{- test}
procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  IA1, IA2: PIntArray;
begin
  Button1.Enabled := False;

  Caption := 'Initializing';
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  new(IA1);
  InitializeArray(IA1);

  { copy randomized array }
  new(IA2);
  IA2^ := IA1^;

  { sort traditionally }
  Caption := 'Sorting1';
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  Sort1(IA1);

  Caption := 'Checking1';
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  Check(IA1);

  { sort using parallel library }
  Caption := 'Sorting2';
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  Sort2(IA2);

  Caption := 'Checking2';
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  Check(IA2);

  Caption := 'Done';
  Button1.Enabled := True;
end;

end.
```

Comment: You realize that you are recursively creating tasks/futures in your implementation?

Comment: Yes, I do realize that - is that a no-no?

Comment: What do you think happens when you create 1000000 or more threads?

Comment: I'm not creating any threads. I fully expect the parallel library to automatically limit the number of threads created to something reasonable relatively to the number of cores I have available, but I guess perhaps my expectations are too high?

Comment: Your expectations are wrong.

Comment: You can specify a `TThreadPool` as second parameter for  `TTask.Future` but it won't help you much in this case.

Comment: I don't see why the threading library will do what @Stefan implies. I think your expectations are reasonable. The threading library will use a thread pool and not over subscribe. I would say though that once the sub-array becomes small enough, you should switch away from a threaded approach. Small enough is probably larger than you think considering the overhead of creating and scheduling a task.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: in fact it does exactly what Stefan implies (in my case DelphiXE7 does this).

Comment: Even if it would it would run into some deadlock at some point where all the futures are waiting on their nested futures that cannot be processed because all threads are already used. You cannot recursively create tasks and expect them to work with limited resources.

Comment: @StefanGlienke OK, that's probably the reason for the design then isn't it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is recursively creating futures (tasks) that are not in context to each other. So the PPL does not know anything about their relation and happily creates threads for each of them (call that a design flaw and report it if you want).

So make a quick sort properly perform in parallel you need to partition the input data and then pass it to several tasks once and not recursively. So the fix would be to call `Sort1R` inside the future and not `Sort2R`.

For further information I suggest doing a research what sorting algorithms are working well in parallel.

The PPL is not a magic silver bullet that turns any code in well performing parallel code. It just simplifies and abstracts the API required to handle tasks/threads.

Comment: Calling Sort1R from the "future" would probably make the code work again, sure, but then it wouldn't scale beyond two threads.

Comment: Then you need to improve that and wrap the call of the future creation into some function that determines if it can fork or if it continues to run in serial.

Comment: Indeed, but that's the kinds of design decisions I was hoping the parallel lib would have already made for me. Oh, well.